# How is epoll_wait implemented in Linux for x86_64

Tags: linux-kernel

I would like to know how `epoll_wait` syscall is implemented in Linux for x86_64. I grepped on the source code and found an entry-point named `sys_epoll_wait`. However, I couldn't find the implementation of it. Could anyone point to me the correct file I need to look up for this specific syscall. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in `fs/eventpoll.c`:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE4(epoll_wait, int, epfd, struct epoll_event __user *, events,
    int, maxevents, int, timeout)
```